# Нюансы методов при сериализации/десериализации в Java

Tags: java

Объясните, пожалуйста, нюансы метода `defaultwriteobject()`, `defaultreadobject()` при процессах сериализации/десериализации в java:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable{


     // ....

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException{

            out.defaultWriteObject();
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)

                throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

            in.defaultReadObject();
    }

    //......

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никаких особенных нюансов у `defaultWriteObject` и `defaultReadObject` нет.

Если вы оставите ваш код как есть, то будет обычная сериализация/десериализация.

Если вы хотите написать полностью свой способ сериализации/десериализации, то уберите использование `defaultWriteObject` и `defaultReadObject`, и потом напишите в методах `writeObject`/`readObject` свой код.

Если хотите дополнить, или сериализовать несериализуемое (извините за тавтологию) поле, то оставляете `defaultWriteObject` и `defaultReadObject` и дописываете сериализацию этого поля.

Answer (score 0):

При десериализации "по умолчанию" (равно как и методом defaultReadObject) выполняется конструктор без параметров первого (в иерархии наследования) несериализованного родительского класса. Т.е. если у класса А нет конструктора без параметров, то будет ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

"При десериализации "по умолчанию" (равно как и методом defaultReadObject) выполняется конструктор без параметров первого (в иерархии наследования) несериализованного родительского класса. Т.е. если у класса А нет конструктора без параметров, то будет ошибка."

подскажите, а разве при десериализации по умолчанию выполняется конструктор без параметров? Вроде бы, конструктор без параметров при реализации Serializable по умолчанию не требуется. Или я не правильно понимаю тему?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).